# Can you add a count function within a sum function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Pretty new to MySQL; however, I'm having troubles with some errors. I'm trying to have a stored procedure that tells us the number of invoices that have a balance due.

So if, `greater than 0` ...and then add up all those invoices with a balance.

If the balance of those invoices is `greater than or equal to 30,000` then display a message giving the number of invoices with a balance and the sum of those.

Else, `if it is less than 30,000` then display a message saying total balance is less than 30,000.

Thanks for the help!

Please note, that the code I have now. It gives me an error on `SUM`. Is there a way to make my select statement better?

My Code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_balance_due_count INT;
    DECLARE var_balance_due_sum DECIMAL(9,2);

    SELECT
        (invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total) AS balance_due,
        COUNT(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total) INTO var_balance_due_count,
        SUM(var_balance_due_count) INTO var_balance_due_sum
    FROM
        invoices
    WHERE
        invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total > 0;


    IF var_balance_due_sum >= 30000 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('There is ', var_balance_due_count, ' invoices.', 'Together their balance due is: $',  var_balance_due_sum) AS message;
    ELSE 
        SELECT CONCAT('Total balance due is less than $30,000.') AS message;
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `SUM` per se, it is the way you are using `INTO`, it should be after all the select expressions. Note that I don't see why you are creating balance_due so have left that out. Also I have corrected your expression for `var_balance_due_sum` according to how I understand your question. So your query should be:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total),
    SUM(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total) 
    INTO var_balance_due_count, var_balance_due_sum
```